# Android ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-sdk

Пытаюсь реализовать список с изображением, можете подсказать, как можно реализовать адаптер который будет доставить изображение(drawable) с ресурсов приложения в зависимости от того какой элемент вставляется?

P.S. Пытаюсь реализовать что-то вроде телефонного справочника где список сортируется по алфавиту и перед именем вставляется картинка(большая буква алфавита)

Ниже написал как список должен работать(и он работает, только без изображения)

```
    srch = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.srch);
    list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    srch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Вам поможет любая ссылка в интернете по запросу `android listview custom adapter`. Можете и по сайту поискать.

Comment: Большая буква алфавита делается не через кучу картинок в ресурсах (это очень расточительно), а формируется программно. На гитхабе, кстати есть несколько готовых библиотек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно для этого кастомизировать `ListView` или же `RecyclerView`. 
А для букв используйте библиотеку

```
compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
```

Вот вам [туториал](http://blog.grafixartist.com/create-gmail-style-list-in-android/), где реализуется ваша задача